# How to print awk's results with different colors for different fields?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, awk

```
 ads2 cls create | awk -F [\"] '/^>>> cluster established .../ { strt=1 } strt!=1 { next } $1 ~ "name" { cnt++;nam[cnt]=$2 } $1 ~ "state" {stat[cnt]=$2;print -e "Node "nam[cnt]" has state "$2 } END { if (stat[1]=="3" && stat[2]=="3") { print "Cluster established. Starting session manager" } else { print "Failed" } }
```

the above command gives the output of `ads2 cls create` to `awk` which checks certain output variable and based on that it returns either `"Cluster established. Starting session manager"` or `Failed`

However, I'm trying to color those outputs with `green` for the first and "red" for the second. I searched in the Internet and didn't find anything related to color text that are printed using `print` command, but rather using `echo -e` command.

**So How can I color those two outputs, however with the current implementation!**

the output of the command `ads2 cls create` can be seen below

```
kernel with pid 3336 (port 9011) killed
kernel with pid 16406 (port 9011) killed
probing service daemon @ http://xx.xx.x.xx:9010
starting kernel FDT-NB-0144 @ http://xx.xx.0.xx:9011 name=xx-NB-0144 max_consec_timeouts=10 clustermode=Standard hostname=FDT-NB-0144 framerate=20000 schedmode=Standard rtaddr=xx.xx.x.xx tickrole=Local tickmaster=local max_total_timeouts=1000
kernel FDT-NB-0144 running
probing service daemon @ http://xx.xx.xx.xx:9010
starting kernel fdt-c-agx-0008 @ http://xx.xx.xx.18:9011 name=fdt-c-agx-0008 max_consec_timeouts=10 clustermode=Standard hostname=nvidia@fdt-c-agx-0008 framerate=20000 schedmode=Standard rtaddr=xx.xx.xx.xx tickrole=Local tickmaster=local max_total_timeouts=1000
kernel fdt-c-agx-0008 running
>>> start cluster establish ...
>>> cluster established ...
        nodes {
            node {
                name = "xxx-c-agx-0008";
                address = "http://xx.xx.xx.xx:9011/";
                state = "3";
            }
            node {
                name = "xxx-NB-0144";
                address = "http://xx.xx.0.xx:9011/";
                state = "3";
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ANSI color sequences inside an awk printf command as follows:

```
awk 'BEGIN{printf "\x1b[32m%s\x1b[0m\n", "Succeeded"}'

awk 'BEGIN{printf "\x1b[31m%s\x1b[0m\n", "Failed"}'
```

ex:

[image]

To apply it in your case, modify the `END` block to:

```
  END { 
    if (stat[1]=="3" && stat[2]=="3") { 
      printf "\x1b[32mCluster established. Starting session manager\x1b[0m\n" } 
    else { 
      printf "\x1b[31mFailed\x1b[0m\n" 
    } 
  }
```

Comment: I can't integrate it to my command. I tried: `ads2 cls create | awk -F [\"] '/^>>> cluster established .../ { strt=1 } strt!=1 { next } $1 ~ "name" { cnt++;nam[cnt]=$2 } $1 ~ "state" {stat[cnt]=$2;print -e "Node "nam[cnt]" has state "$2 } END { if (stat[1]=="3" && stat[2]=="3") { 'BEGIN{printf "\x1b[32m%s\x1b[0m\n", "Cluster established. Starting session manager"}' } else { print "Failed" } }' . However, it didn't work
`

Comment: @k.jbaili I only used a `BEGIN` block because I don't have access to the `ads2` commands - you should **not** include that in your code. Please edit your question to include a testable example of the `ads2 cls create` command output

Comment: I've added the output of the command ads2 cls create

Comment: @k.jbaili please see updated answer

Comment: thank you. this works