# How do I underline formatted output in awk?

Tags: bash, awk

I am new to awk and having a hard time figuring out how to format output with underlines. It doesn't appear to be possible to use formatting escape sequences in awk e.g. \e[4m?

Is there a way to underline "Name" "Email" and "Phone" without printing a new line of underscores?

Heres my code:

```
awk -F";" 'BEGIN 
           {printf "%-20s %-20s %s\n\n ", " Name", "email", " Phone "}
           {printf "%-20s %-20s %s\n ",$1,$2,$3}'
```

Comment: You can use essentially the same as [How to print awk's results with different colors for different fields?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1326271/how-to-print-awks-results-with-different-colors-for-different-fields)

Comment: Thank you for linking to this. My error was in trying to apply the ANSI underline sequence to "Name" etc. instead of the modifier string. Also had to replace "\e[4m " with "\033[4m" which did the trick as outlined here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29983248/ansi-escapes-dont-work-in-printf

Comment: Yes, you can represent the escape character `\e` as either octal `\033` or (as I did in the linked question) hexadecimal `\x1b` - your choice